# Numpy Referenced before assignment error in python

Tags: python

here is my python code:

```
import numpy
class test:
  def __init__(self,):
    print(numpy.__version__)
    if False:
      numpy = None

if __name__=='__main__':
  print(numpy.__version__)
  T = test()
```

when I run this code, the interpreter give me an error showed blow:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'numpy' referenced before assignment
```

It seems like, before executing `numpy = None`, imported module "numpy" has been covered while there is no numpy variable.

My question is what exactly the interpreter did during initializing a class(not object)?

Comment: Why are you assigning `numpy = None`? This makes Python think `numpy` is a local variable.

Comment: If your function contains an assignment to a variable, then by default the variable is local to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: As a reply to your comment, Python goes through each line of code before executing it, and sees that the syntax is correct and other things. To test it, run the following code.

```py
def foo():
    print("Hello, I won't be printed.")
    : # Syntax Error!!!
foo()
```

It will raise a `SyntaxError` without printing anything even though the `SyntaxError` is after the `print` statement, because it checks the code and then only runs it.

Inside a function, it also thinks that all the variables which are found to be assigned while checking are supposed to be local. If you don't want this, then you must explicitly say so using the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords.

```py
class test:
  def __init__(self,):
    global numpy
    print(numpy.__version__)
    if False:
      numpy = None
```

Comment: @Asocia, Done. What does OP stand for?

Comment: The code is meaningless, just  for reproducing the issue I met. But I am confused why the variable is local before excuating `numpy = None`

Comment: The codes are excuated line by line, so why `numpy = None` will influence the previous ussage of numpy? What did python interpreter do to the class before initializing it?

Comment: thx for your answer, it works. It seems like a rule of python, so why don't python convert numpy to local variable until assignment executed?

Comment: almost all the variables can be covered while assigning, why global variable cannot be covered by local variable? It is a technical limit or a thoughtful design?

Comment: No, Python check the code before running, and if there is any variables assigned in that function, I suppose it sets away some space in the local scope for it and labels it as local or something like that.

Comment: It's a thoughtful design, you can use the same variable name inside and outside of functions and it won't conflict. That strange error message is saying that Python has set labeled this variable as local, and knows that it may be set, but you are referring to it before it has been set. Note: If it's correct, please accept the answer.